# Java, EJB framework, RBAC

Tags: java, ejb, rbac

Can any body give me idea how to do RBAC with the help of **EJB** framework? I am new in Java, so I need details description about EJB and RBAC.

Comment: EJB is not needed to implement RBAC in Java, using jCasbin would be enough: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin

Answer (score 2):

There is [JAAS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jaas/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

EJB itself wont help you with your need for [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control).

The [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) framework suggested by ***atamanroman*** will provide authentication and authorization but not an RBAC implementation.

What you need is a Java implementation of RBAC.

I have implemented and extended my own (for academic purposes) so I'm not too familiar with them but I believe you may be interested in [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).